# Functional dependencies transition and union

Tags: functional-dependencies

I've been thinking that,

I know that:
if a→bc
and we know a→a(trivial)
then a→abc by Union is right
So this is like we can put the left hand side element to the right

But if that is also true?
if a→bc
and we know b→b(trivial)
then by union, ab→bc??
Feeling kind of weird, but if this could work, it's like we can also pick any right hand side element and put in to the left side.
Is this true?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If a→bc then ad→bc for any attribute d (whether it appears in this functional dependency or not). Indeed, by [the reflexivity axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) ad→a, and then ad→bc by the transitivity axiom from ad→a and a→bc.